# How to insert bootstrap in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement bootstrap in my website which is in wordpress the url is this http://www.bolsapubli.net but i don't know where to insert the lines to import css to my website, somebody knows where to introduce this lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `/wp-content/themes/yoo_cloud_wp` and find `header.php` and add you CSS there.

Another method is with use of [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) hook in `functions.php` file.